# Python Pygame Shape Rotation Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, rotation, pygame

I'm fairly new to Pygame and i'm trying it out making a simple little game, i'm currently having issues rotation a rectangle. The shape in it's self rotates however for some reason when the shape rotates say 90degrees it floats a few pixels from the floor, here's an image to show what happens:

[image]

```
    #Player Class
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the bar at the bottom that the player
        controls. """


    # List of sprites we can bump against
    level = None

    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor function """

        # Call the parent's constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.width = 40
        self.height = 60
        self.image = pygame.Surface([self.width, self.height])
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.baseImage = self.image        

        # Set a referance to the image rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        """ Move the player. """

        # Move left/right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        # See if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right,
            # set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

    # Player-controlled movement:
    def go_left(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the left arrow. """
        self.change_x = -10

    def go_right(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the right arrow. """
        self.change_x = 10

    def stop(self):
        """ Called when the user lets off the keyboard. """
        self.change_x = 0

    def turn_r(self):       
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
        self.change_x = 0

    def turn_l(self):
        count = -90
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
        self.change_x = -0
```

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------

```
 while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
                done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.go_left()                
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.go_right()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.jump()
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player.turn_r()
                    count += 90
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    player.turn_l()
                    count -= 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appear to be the top and left of the shape, you might want to realign the center, something like:

```
def turn_r(self):       
    center_x = self.rect.x + (self.rect.width / 2)
    center_y = self.rect.y + (self.rect.height / 2)

    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)

    new_center_x = self.rect.x + (self.rect.width / 2)
    new_center_y = self.rect.y + (self.rect.height / 2)

    self.change_x = center_x - new_center_x
    self.change_y = center_y - new_center_y
```

Or you can set the new Y for the shape to return to bottom:

```
def turn_r(self):       
    bottom = self.rect.y + self.rect.height
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
    new_bottom = self.rect.y + self.rect.height
    self.change_y = bottom - new_bottom
```

I don't know PyGame well, the code can have some issues but it is something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Before turning it by 90° the width is 40 and the height is 60. After you turned it these two values are exchanged, so the height is now only 40 while your code still blits it at a height referring to the original 60 pixels.

I'd say the easiest way is to make the program turn the image and reset is to another height level which lies those 20 pixels difference lower than before.

Comment: I see but the thing is that when it rotates the visible shape rotates but for some reason the actual physical rectangle stays in the same position, so for example when i rotate it and move it to a wall, half of the shape goes through it. Thanks for your help though i'll play around with it to try and fix it! Cheers pal

Answer (score 0):

Just to help others out i've just figured out what was wrong with the code. The issue was that after the shape got rotated the rect stayed the same, i fixed this by simply updated the rect in the turn_r and turn_l functions. Feel free to ask for help!